# Parameter is not added to logfile even though when calling function parameter value is given

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, directory, scripting

I have a PowerShell script which deletes folders in a directory. Everytime a folder is deleted, it should generate a log entry in a logfile which will be created each time the script runs. when calling the log function to run, after a folder gets deleted, it should also send the information to the log for what happened exactly, so was it already deleted, was there an error when deleting it or was it successful. I tried to write all this in a function called "Logs". Most of it works only the part where I want to check if there was an error when deleting the folders or if it worked.
Here is the script so you can see. I would be very grateful if someone would find the issue and could help me with this problem.

```
# Variables

$Folders = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\user1\OneDrive\Documents\000_pwsh\012_IAM\DoD\test_folders.csv"
# This path right here is just for testing.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Variables for Log functions
$currentDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy_MM_dd__HH_mm_ss"
$logFilename = "deleteDoD_$currentDate.log"
#$logFilePath = "C:\scripts\DoD_cleanup\Logs_testing\$logFilename"
$logFilePath = "C:\Logs\$logFilename"
# Variables for Timers
$scriptStartTime = Get-Date

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Functions

function Logs {
    param (
        [string]$action,
        [bool]$success,
        [string]$logFilePath
        #[bool]$folderExists # Folder Exists AFTER DELETION YES/NO
    )
    try {
        if (-not (Test-Path $logFilePath)) {
            New-Item -Path $logFilePath -ItemType File -Force | Out-Null
        }
        if ($success) {
            $status = "Successfully deleted"
            <#if (Test-Path $action) {
                $status = "Error occurred while deleting"
            } else {
                $status = "Successfully deleted" 
            }#>
        }
        else {
            $status = "Folder not found (probalby already deleted)"
        }

        #checkFolderExists
        if ($folderExists) {
            if (Test-Path $folder.Folders) {
                $deleteError = "Error when deleting Folder!!"
            }
            else {
                $deleteError = "Folder already deleted"
            }
        }
        

        $logEntry = "[{0}] Action: {1} | Status: {2} | Error: {3}" -f ($currentDate), $action, $status, $deleteError
        $logEntry | Out-File -Append -FilePath $logFilePath

        # Running only when deleting all folders is finished!!
        if (-not (Get-Content -Path $logFilePath | Select-string -Pattern "Script Execution Time")) {
            # Append running time to log file
            $executionTimeEntry | Out-File -Append -FilePath $logFilePath
        }
    } catch {
        # Error Handling for reference in Logfile
        # Add-Content -Path $logFilePath -Value "Error during log function execution: $_"
    }
}


# Show live running time Counter
function LiveCounter {
    $elapsedTime = (Get-Date) - $scriptStartTime
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "-------------------------------------------------------"
    Write-Host "Running Time: $($elapsedTime.Hours):$($elapsedTime.Minutes):$($elapsedTime.Seconds)"
    Write-Host "-------------------------------------------------------"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Progress Bar
$progressParams = @{
    Activity = "Deleting Folders"
    Status   = "Preparing to delete"
    PercentComplete = 0
}
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Delete Folders
foreach ($index in 0..($Folders.Count - 1)) {
    $folder = $Folders[$index]
        if (Test-Path $folder.Folders) {
            # Progress Counter
            $progressParams.PercentComplete = [math]::Round(($index / $Folders.Count) * 100, 2)
            # Progressbar 
            $progressParams.Status = "Progress: $($progressParams.PercentComplete)% complete"
            Write-Progress @progressParams
            try {
                # Remove the Folders!
                Remove-Item $folder.Folders -Recurse -Force
                $success = $true
            }
            catch {
                $success = $false
                if (Test-Path $folder.Folders) {
                    Logs -action "Delete $($folder.Folders)" -success $success -logFilePath $logFilePath -folderExists $true
                } else {
                    Logs -action "Delete $($folder.Folders)" -success $success -logFilePath $logFilePath -folderExists $false
                }
            }
            Logs -action "Delete $($folder.Folders)" -success $success -logFilePath $logFilePath
            # Calling the Live Counter Function
            LiveCounter
        }
        else {
            Logs -action "Delete $($folder.Folders)" -success $false -logFilePath $logFilePath
        }
}
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$progressParams.PercentComplete = 100
$progressParams.Status = "All Folders deleted."
Write-Progress @progressParams -Completed
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

$endTime = Get-Date
$executionTime = $endTime - $scriptStartTime
Write-Host "Script Execution Time: $executionTime"
# Logging Execution Time
Logs -action "Script Execution Time: $executionTime" -logFilePath $logFilePath
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to move the $folderExists parameter to a new function and connect this new function with the Logs function, which didn't work, I also tried numerous other solutions which I found about online, but none of them worked. So if anyone has an idea on how to solve this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Change the parameter type from `[bool]` to `[switch]`, then change the command invocation to `Logs -FolderExists` (when the folder exists), and `Logs` (without the parameter at all, for when it doesnt exist)